# hibernate bulk update with batching

Tags: hibernate, jdbc, hibernate-batch-updates

I have a code which updates a bunch or records of a table using hibernate bulk update feature (update table set=:arg where id =:id ...), in a for loop. So, if there are 100 records to be updated then 100 times the update is fired from hibernate. Is there a way to package these multiple updates into a single batch update (read jdbc batch) (or at least reduce the updates fired)?
I understand hibernate performs batching implicitly but in the above case it does not seem to be happening.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate tries to [batch DML operations](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/5/html/Performance_Tuning_Guide/sect-Performance_Tuning_Guide-Entity_Beans-Batching_Database_Operations.html) during flush time, so make user you set the following properties:

```
<property name="hibernate.order_inserts" value="true"/>
<property name="hibernate.order_updates" value="true"/>
<property name="hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size" value="20"/>
<property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="50"/>
```

Also take into consideration that an IDENTITY generator will [disable JDBC batching](http://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-identity-sequence-and-table-sequence-generator/).